# Twilio Errors 30007 & 30003

Tags: twilio

I am new here.  I have been Using Twilio for about over 7 years now.  My company sends out between 700k - 2.3m SMS per month.  We starting yesterday have started receiving mostly 30007 & 30003.

We have registered our messages with the A2P 10DLC and have not had issues for a long time.  Twilio is not being very helpful and this is causing our customers to drop off.  I need some advice from the community if any of you have any.  I would really appreciate any help you can offer.

I have changed numbers, modified the messages.  Everything I can think of.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Nicolas. Just wanted to let you know that your message has been seen and we're working, internally, to find a resolution for you. I or another member of the team will post an update as soon as more information is available.

Comment: In the meantime, I'm not sure if you're aware, but here is the documentation for both of those error codes: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30007 &  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30003

Comment: You're not alone. We send a lot more and since 5/19, we'll have 6+ hours of 50% success rate due to 30007 errors. We usually see it in the afternoon. Nothing has helped really. Twilio said they adjusted something, but then the problem shifted to a different number.

Comment: We're having the same issues, and it's maddening. We've also been customers for 7+ years, and we are using registered A2P campaigns, but a large percentage of messages are being filtered for carrier violation. I've had a support ticket open for over 2 months, and so far, they're still "looking into it". Does anyone have experience working with Twilio competitors? At this point, they're costing us money and it's going to force us to switch